# Cannot resolve method setAdapter After Migrating to Androidx

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, androidx

I have tried to go through similar questions but none of them fixed my issue. Before I migrated to androidx this line

```
slideViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)
```

was fine now it throws an error

> Cannot resolve method 'setAdapter(com.fundi.passenger.home.submenu.home.HomeFragment.MyPagerAdapter)'

And `slideIndicator.setViewPager(slideViewPager)`

> setViewPager
>   (androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager)in CircleIndicator cannot be applied
>   to (cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager)

Bellow is part of my code

```
   import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
   import cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager;
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public ArrayList<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<>();
     AutoScrollViewPager slideViewPager;

           @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetBannerResponseJson> call, Response<GetBannerResponseJson> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    banners = response.body().data;
                    Log.e("Image", response.body().data.get(0).foto);
                    MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), banners);
                    slideViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                    slideIndicator.setViewPager(slideViewPager);
                    slideViewPager.setInterval(6000);
                    slideViewPager.startAutoScroll(6000);
                }
            }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 5;
        public ArrayList<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Banner> banners) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.banners = banners;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return banners.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return SlideFragment.newInstance(banners.get(position).id, banners.get(position).foto);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Be sure to update your build.gradle as explained here:https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx#using_androidx This will make libraries that use old support libraries use AndroidX instead.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've already done that boss

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the external library is not compatible with AndroidX. **(Assuming by looking at it's GitHub history)**

> I found this library having AndroidX compatibility:
>   https://github.com/siralam/LoopingViewPager

One way is also, to use Android's native libraries and `import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`

Sample:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(first, "First");
adapter.addFragment(second, "Second");
adapter.addFragment(third, "Third");
myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

// Auto Scroll
Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable update = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
            currentPage = 0;
        }
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
    }
};


new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(update);
    }
}, 100, 500);
```

You will have to update your code implement this.